# How to prevent duplicate data in sql databse

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a form where i save students login data to a database. The form includes the "admission_number", "username" and "password" fields. i want to show an error if the admission number is already existing and a user tries to add it again. Here's my php code for inserting the record.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $server     = 'localhost';
        $username   = 'root';
        $password   = '';

        $course_code=$_POST['course_code'];
        $course_title=$_POST['course_title'];
        $course_units=$_POST['course_units'];
        $course_semester=$_POST['course_semester'];


        $con=($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] = mysqli_connect($server,  $username,   $password));
        if(!$con)
        {
        exit('Error: could not establish connection to the server');
        }
        else
        {
        $con_db=((bool)mysqli_query($con, "USE esther"));
        if(!$con_db)
        {
        exit('Error: Failed to connect to the database');
        }
        else
        {
        if(!empty($course_code) && !empty($course_title) && !empty($course_units) && !empty($course_semester))
    {
        $insert="INSERT INTO `course_table` VALUES('', '".$course_code."' ,'".$course_title."','".$course_units."','".$course_semester."')";
        $query=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $insert);   
        $dup_admission_number = mysql_query("SELECT admission_number FROM users_table WHERE admission_number = $admission_number");
    }
    if (@mysql_query($dup_admission_number)) {
        echo 'Your admission number is already in our database.';
    exit;
    }

        if($query)
        {
                echo 'course added successfully!';
                header("location:add_course.php");      
        }
        else { echo 'Error while adding Course.'; }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '*** fields cannot be blank ***.';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: you realize that you're mixing MySQL APIs here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: you're also outputting before header

Comment: Fourth parameter of `mysqli_connect` is the database. Don't need `$con_db=((bool)mysqli_query($con, "USE esther"));`. You also are open to SQL injections. You can use a `unique` constraint to require columns have unique values; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html. `$admission_number` also appears to never be assigned..

Answer (score 0):

To check admission number is unique or not you have to execute bellow query

$sql: "select id from student where admission_number = <> LIMIT 0,1";

if this query show result then you current form's admission number is not unique.

this process you can do using ajax request or you can check it before insert query being process.

or you can manage it in mysql by giving unique key constraint to admission number.

Comment: Did you not read any of the comments left under their question?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Mysql Query

```
    INSERT INTO sometable (data1, data2, data13) 
  SELECT 'username' FROM sometable
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT username FROM sometable WHERE login='someusername');
```